# I got a "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when using DeleteIndexRequest

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to delete an index named "aaaa_test_a" using "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client", but I got a "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when running the following code.

```
@Test
    public void deleteTest() {
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("192.168.207.132", 9200, "http")));
        DeleteIndexRequest deleteIndexRequest = new DeleteIndexRequest("aaaa_test_a");
        try {
            client.indices().delete(deleteIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse.fromXContent(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/XContentParser;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/support/master/AcknowledgedResponse;

    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete(IndicesClient.java:93)
    at cn.db2es.autoindex.elasticsearch.ESIndexDeleterTest.deleteTest(ESIndexDeleterTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse.fromXContent(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/XContentParser;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/support/master/AcknowledgedResponse;
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
    ... 24 more
```

The version of Elasticsearch is 6.5.3 and the version of RestHighLevelClient is 6.5.3, too.
I wrote the above code with reference to the official tutorial:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/java-rest-high-delete-index.html

Comment: run into the same issue. Solution is highly appreciated.